# How do I make a concrete type after using MakeGenericMethod in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, generics, casting, task

A bit of background, I'm working with some code someone else wrote. It's a REST API that you can issue queries and commands to and they are handled in a generic fashion.

The method for resolving queries is like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("query")]
public async Task<Task> ResolveQuery(ApiQuery message)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(message.QueryType, true);
    var query = this.serializer.Deserialize(message.Payload, type);
    var interfaceType = type.GetGenericInterfaces(typeof(IQuery<>)).FirstOrDefault();
    var responseType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var handleMethod = typeof(IQueryBus).GetMethod("ResolveAsync").MakeGenericMethod(responseType);
    var task = handleMethod.Invoke(this.bus, new object[] { query }) as Task;
    await task;
    return task;
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's very unusual to be using tasks in this way.

So when the handleMethod is invoked, even though it's result is being cast as a Task, and I can see a *valid* result when I mouse over it during debugging, there is no `task.Result` member for me to use for eventual casting.

Things I've tried:

I've tried casting this handleMethod.Invoke as the 'resopnseType' I need, using `Convert.ChangeType(result, responseType);` but I get an exception for not implementing IConvertible. Do I really have to implement IConvertible for every type that I need returned?

I've also tried having the return type set to Task, but I then need to specify TResponse in ResolveQuery and this gets an internal server error (I'm not sure how I specify the TResponse from my calling code).

I've also tried asking the programmer what he was doing here. He does not know. He was following another programmer's original advice for this implementation, but that programmer isn't here at present, otherwise I'd be asking him!

Can anyone tell me how to correctly get my result from the task object and return it, in a RESTful manner, to the calling client?

**Update** - in response to @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev

```
public interface IQueryBus
{
    Task<TResponse> ResolveAsync<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query);
}
```

Comment: There is no `Result`, because it is just a `Task`. You need to cast it to specific `Task<T>` or use reflection once again to get result. Show the code of your `IQueryBus` interface.

Comment: How can I pass in the T needed in Task<T> for casting?

Comment: Could you please share `IQueryBus` code?

Comment: Sorry, I misread you earlier, one moment

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Result`, because it is just a non-generic `Task`.
In order to get result you need a `Task<T>`. Since you don't know `T` in design-time, you need to use reflection again:

```
public async Task<object> ResolveQuery(ApiQuery message)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(message.QueryType, true);

    var query = this.serializer.Deserialize(message.Payload, type);
    var interfaceType = type.GetGenericInterfaces(typeof(IQuery<>)).Single();
    var responseType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    var handleMethod =     typeof(IQueryBus).GetMethod("ResolveAsync").MakeGenericMethod(responseType);
    var task = (Task)handleMethod.Invoke(this.bus, new object[] { query });
    await task;

    return typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(responseType).GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
}
```

It will create a `Result` property for your specific `Task<responseType>` and return its value.

I have slightly updated the existing code too, just as a suggestion:

- Changed `[0]` and `.FirstOrDefault()` to `.Single()` to avoid `NullReferenceException`, because it is expected that there is exactly one value
- Replaced `as Task` to direct cast, because it is expected to be `Task`

Comment: So even though I cast it as a Task (i.e. returning void) it can have a Result?

Comment: @Chucky Yes, `task` is of type `Task`, but actually it is `Task<TResult>` where `TResult` is unknown in design time, and you dynamically access its `Task<TResult>.Result` property.

Comment: Superb! I'm unfamiliar with the syntax `Task<>`. I take it this just means you don't have to specific the type?

Comment: @Chucky `Task` is the base class, it contains all the logic of tasks, but has no `Result`. Basically, it is an asynchronous equivalent of `void`. So, there is no result returned from `void`. `Task<TResult>` is inherited from `Task` and represents asynchronous method which returns `TResult`. `Task<T>` has additional property named `Result` of type `T`, so this is what you need through reflection if you want to get the result of a task.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered that very same problem few weeks ago. Unfortunately I can't find the page where I read that sacred sentence but here it is:

"Awaiting generic methods through reflection is only possible with cast to `dynamic` which resolves in Task< target type>"

So to give you an example how it should look in your case:

```
dynamic taskResult = await (dynamic)handleMethod.Invoke(this.bus, new object[] { query });
```

Yes, dynamic is not the best thing but helps in such scenarios where the compiler has no idea of what type would the generic T parameter.

Comment: this answer and Yeldar's both work for me. I'm unsure which is better so I'm going to upvote both and maybe wait for more discussion before marking either as correct.

Comment: General recommendation is not to use `dynamic` unless you have to. Your case can be considered to be "you have to", because it is more readable than reflection, and approximately as bad in terms of performance. Personally I would not use `dynamic`, because I never use it in my code, but it is arguable and mostly a matter of taste and team coding style preferences.